# QuantLib-Python: where is the function to take Period to years?

Tags: programming, quantlib

The C++ version of QuantLib has a function called [years](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/2012/10/quantlib-periods-time-units-and-frequencies/):

```
Real years(const &Period p);
```

I don't see this in QuantLib-Python version 1.18.  Is it supposed to be there or was it not SWIGed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not swigged AFAIK.
As a workaround, you can retrieve this information by using `p.units()` and `p.length()` that are available (if. `p` is your period):

- `p.length()` returns the length of the period
- `p.units()` will return an integer giving you the unit (0 for days, 1 for weeks, 2 for months, etc.), according to: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/ab15e33d7feb23b5f204037e16b64c6d1ea7a05f/SWIG/date.i#L135-L136

For example:

```
p = ql.Period("1Y3M")
p.units()
# returns 2 (i.e. ql.Months)
p.length()
# returns 15
```

Your function will look something like:

```
def ql_period_in_years(period):
    units = period.units()
    if units == ql.Days:
        denominator = 365
    elif units == ql.Weeks:
        denominator = 52
    elif units == ql.Months:
        denominator = 12
    ...
    return period.length() / denominator
```

For the example above:

```
   ql_period_in_years(p)
   # returns 1.25
```